# Android studio, ability to select both v1 and v2 signing method of apk

Tags: android-studio, google-play

I have a project in android studio. I was going to sign it and send it to google play.

At first build I just selected the v2 signing method as it was the recommended. When uploading that apk, google play complains that the jar is not signed.

Therefore I want to change signing method to both v1 and v2.

Problem: I can not find how to change to both v1 and v2 as the option is not available anymore in the Generate Signed Apk-dialog anymore and I and not find any setting for it and can not find help on the internet.

PS This feels a bit stupid as it should be something simple and I think there are some help on the internet but I just can not find it.

Comment: On the generate signed apk dialog on the last page when there is a finish button there are 2 check boxes on the bottom make sure they are both checked that will fix it

Comment: Doh! @JRowan. I was thinking they where not there, but I understood it was something stupid by me. I forgot there are several dialogs in the signing process. "last page" was the magic that made me remember. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Credits should go to @JRowan if any but...:
The check buttons are not on the first dialog, but at the bottom of the second dialog.